# Why am I getting a TypeError when I have more than one jQuery UI slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, typeerror

I have multiple sliders on a page, assigned IDs and with custom data, but otherwise the same. For some strange reason, only the first one ever works, the second always errors with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`. I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong here, am I missing something obvious? This seems to be a difficult issue to research with TypeErrors being so generic.

First/working slider:

```
var valMap = ["Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Buzz"];

var slider = $('#slider_1');
var sliderVal = $('#slider_val_1');

slider.slider({
    animate: "fast",
    min: 0,
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    value: 0,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        // Some logic
    },
    change: myChangeFunction
});
```

Second/broken slider:

```
var valMap = ["This", "That", "Those", "Them"];

var slider = $('#slider_2');
var sliderVal = $('#slider_val_2');

slider.slider({
    animate: "fast",
    min: 0,
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    value: 0,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        // Some logic
    },
    change: myChangeFunction
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var valMap = ["Any", "40", "50", "55", "60", "65", "70", "80", "85", "90", "100", "110", "120", "140", "150", "160", "190"];
  var ajaxValMap = ["", "901000072", "901000052", "901000069", "901000055", "901000073", "901000084", "901000081", "901000086", "901000058", "901000077", "901000083", "901000082", "901000050", "901000067", "901000066", "901000064"];

  jQuery.ui.slider.prototype.widgetEventPrefix = 'slider';

  var slider = $('#slider_1');
  var sliderVal = $('#slider_val_1');

  slider.slider({
    animate: "fast",
    //range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      sliderVal
        .text(valMap[ui.value] + " <");

      if (ui.value == 0) {
        slider.attr('value', null);
        sliderVal
          .text(valMap[ui.value]);
      } else {
        var ajaxIds = ajaxValMap.slice(ui.value, valMap.length);
        slider.attr('value', ajaxIds.join(','));
      }
    },
    //change: comboValueChange
  });

  var sliderValues = slider.slider("option", "values");

  sliderVal
    .val(valMap[sliderValues[0]] + " - " + valMap[sliderValues[1]]);
});

jQuery(function($) {
  var valMap = ["Any", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "15", "23", "39", "45", "55", "60", "91"];
  var ajaxValMap = ["", "804000066", "804000083", "804000085", "804000063", "804000086", "804000067", "804000082", "804000058", "804000077", "804000084", "804000073", "804000072", "804000070", "804000069", "804000078"];

  jQuery.ui.slider.prototype.widgetEventPrefix = 'slider';

  var slider = $('#slider_4');
  var sliderVal = $('#slider_val_4');

  slider.slider({
    animate: "fast",
    //range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      sliderVal
        .text(valMap[ui.value] + " <");

      if (ui.value == 0) {
        slider.attr('value', null);
        sliderVal
          .text(valMap[ui.value]);
      } else {
        var ajaxIds = ajaxValMap.slice(ui.value, valMap.length);
        slider.attr('value', ajaxIds.join(','));
      }
    },
    //change: comboValueChange
  });

  var sliderValues = slider.slider("option", "values");

  sliderVal
    .val(valMap[sliderValues[0]] + " - " + valMap[sliderValues[1]]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id='slider_1'></div>
<div id='slider_val_1'></div>
<div id='slider_4'></div>
<div id='slider_val_4'></div>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice! :)

Comment: Maybe javascript is getting called before the element $('#slider_2') is present in the DOM. Can you provide the HTML being used?

Comment: Your code looks ok. So the problem in that place that you do not.

Comment: Added fiddle to the question. Also JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/opmxbb87/1/

Comment: use slider.slider();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the jQuery UI documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-values), "values" is a method, not an option. You need to use:

```js
slider.slider("values");
```

instead of

```
slider.slider("option", "values");
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jimbo2150/opmxbb87/2/